# How can I remedy a "load glyph" error when making matplotlib plots with multiprocessing?

Tags: python, matplotlib, multiprocessing, ipython

My code is returning the following error when using multiprocessing to generate plots with matplotlib.  The code has been simplified.  Does anyone know how to remedy?

> File
>   "/home/rhh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_pdf.py",
>   line 2173, in get_text_width_height_descent
>       font.set_text(s, 0.0, flags=LOAD_NO_HINTING) RuntimeError: In set_text: could not load glyph

```
import multiprocessing as mt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def plot_multi(data1,paths1,data2,paths2):
     q1 = mt.Queue();q2 = mt.Queue();
     p1=mt.Process(target=fxn,args=(q1,data1,paths1,"s1","s2"))
     p2=mt.Process(target=fxn,args=(q2,data2,paths2,"s3","s4")) 
     p1.start();p2.start();
     p1.join();p2.join();
     a1=mq1.get()
     a2=mq2.get()
     return a1,a2

def fxn(oq1,y,ypaths,str1,str2):
    plt.clf()
    r,c=y.shape
    plt.hist(y,int(r/3))
    plt.ylabel("Counts")
    plt.xlabel("Bins")
    plt.title(str2+' Histogram \n Case 1')
    plt.savefig("./plots/histograms/"+str2+"_"+str1+"_hist.pdf")
    oq1.put((y))
    return
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].